# Bulk CSV, Bulk XML not working as expected

Tags: workbench

When trying to query the results in BULK CSV and upon download the file format is .txt and has a query in it instead of the results. Is any step I am missing or is there any bug related to workbench?

Steps I am performing:

1. Login to workbench
2. Use a query (we can take any object which has high record count)
3. Then choose BULK CSV or BULK XML.
4. After the process is completed, download the job request.
5. You will see the query instead the downloaded file and it will in .txt format.

Comment: The description needs to be edited as "BULK CSV, BULK XML not working as expected in Workbench"

Comment: You can make that change yourself by making an [edit] (this is the same link as the "edit" text that appears under the tags on the desktop site).

Answer (score 2):

You're simply clicking on the wrong element in Workbench's admittedly confusing Bulk Query UI.

[image: Workbench screenshot]

Click the highlighted envelope icon, *not* the batch Id. Clicking the batch Id downloads the request details, not the results.